# Is 'it' redundant in '... which God hath ordained it' ? (1899 UK)

Tags: grammaticality

I was reading [this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/356/why-do-english-verbs-inflect-so-little-especially-in-regard-to-person#comment2368_356) which linked to Prof Lawler's [PDF](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/LanguageFossils.pdf). I thought to try the Matriculation examination in 1899 just (on p 6 of 6) to test the littleness of my linguistic knowledge:

> 10. "To make a revolution every day  is  the nature of the sun,
>   because of that 
>   necessary course which God hath ordained **IT**,
>    from which ***it*** cannot swerve
>   but by a faculty from that voice
>            which first did give it motion."
>   (i) analyse this sentence

1. Am I right that both ***it*** and **IT**  = the sun?

2. Is there any grammatical error in the dependent clause with **IT**?
It doesn't make sense to write: 'God hath ordained the sun',
because you must specify what God ordained the sun TO DO?

3. Why not omit **IT**, and instead just write: ' ... that 
necessary course God hath ordained, ...' ?

Comment: *It* is the indirect object.

Answer (score 1):

You could think of it like ordaining a priest or minister. It consists not only  of consecrating him for that office, but also assigning certain duties.  Thus the duties assigned to him are "ordained *to* him". This is the sense in which this passage used  "ordain".

So the "course" is something which God has "ordained" (assigned)  **to** the sun.

Comment: Yes- if you insert "to" before the first "it", you will more easily see the meaning.

Comment: It's like giving a dog a bone, except here it's ordaining the sun a course.